# How to Create MenuStrip dynamic (in winform C#.Net) From Database (SQL Server)?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c#-4.0

I want create MenuStrip dynamic (in winform C#.Net 4.0) From Database (SQL Server) and manage that from user Authenticate.

Now, I don't know how to create SQL table, Menu and create event handler for My menu.

Please Help me.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply load the data you want from DB, select what user must see,
then put a container where you want the menuStrip to be (panel for example)
and then use something like:

```
List<string> menuItems = LoadUserMenuItems();
        ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        menu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menuItem);
            item.Text = menuItem;
            item.Click += new EventHandler(item_Click);// item_click is event handler name
            // item.MenuItems.Add(); you could use this to add sub items
        }

        panel1.Controls.Add(menu);
```

but please next time you show some effort

Answer (score 2):

you can create Table into SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MenuItems]
(
[MenuID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MenuTitle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[MenuIdParent] [int] NULL,
[MenuEventHandler] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MenuLanguageID] [int] NOT NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MenuItems] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MenuItems_MenuLanguageID]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [MenuLanguageID]
 GO
```